# How to handle "This branch is n commits ahead, m commits behind develop"?

Tags: git

I'm working on a project and using Git as my Version Control System. So I created a new branch for example "test-branch", from the "develop" branch to contribute to the project. But other developers merged their branches to develop, so now I'm getting the "This branch is 2 commits ahead, 3 commits behind develop.". Because I made 2 commits to my branch ("test-branch") I cannot just pull or merge the develop branch. Is there any solutions to resolve my current branch to sync with the develop branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `git pull --rebase` (or `git pull -r`) to automatically pull and rebase the commits from the remote branch.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull.

Comment: Then does my commits stay right after the commits that I pulled? How does the ordering process?

Comment: Yes, it reorders the commits chronologically.

Comment: Ok I understood. Thanks

Comment: @GG.: technically they're reordered graph-topologically, not chronologically. The effect is often the same though. (The way to get it different is to make complicated topologies and/or use `git rebase -i` to shuffle commits around.)